# What version of Rails is this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails app that I dont know what version it is.

Here is the app directory:
[image]

Comment: You can't see it from just the directory structure.

Comment: How is it then possible to see ? I have looked in the Readme but there is no indication what version it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at your `config/environment.rb` file. You should see a line like:

```
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = 'x.x.x' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION
```

where x.x.x should be your version.

That being said, you also have to make sure that there is no version of Rails in your `vendor` directory, as that will override whatever gem version it might try loading.

Comment: I will approve your answer. It was Rails version 1.2.6

Comment: Where should I find the gems to create a gemfile?

Comment: I don't believe bundler has been tested to "integrate" with Rails 1.2.6 (actually, I'm almost positive it hasn't), but you can still use it to manage your dependencies. Your best bet is to start on bundler's website: http://gembundler.com/.

Answer (score 3):

Check config/environment.rb.

Can you boot the app? If so, start the console, it will tell you the exact version.

Answer (score 0):

There's no Gemfile, that would suggest it's version 2.something

Comment: If it still has the components dir, I think it might be earlier than that, 1.2.3.